# How do I go about investigating Windows Defender alert "VirTool:Win32/ExcludeProc.A"

Tags: windows, windows-10, malware

I received the following notification from Windows Defender several times over the last week.

[image: Windows defender alert]

Things I believe:

- It is malware
- Its attempting to hide things from Windows Defender
- Windows Defender was unable to do anything about it, other than disallow the action

How do I go about further investigating this, like finding out what is actually executing this command?

I also tried reading the "Learn More" link, and installing Kaspersky's anti-malware tools, but it appeared to be unaware of the problem.

Here is some of the text in the alert for people who may search for this in the future:

```
VirTool:Win32/ExcludeProc.A

CmdLine: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C cmd /c powershell.exe -NoP -NonI -W Hidden -exec bypass Add-MpPreference -ExclusionProcess 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe'
```

Comment: What’s the question exactly?  The command being ran is harmless.  However, the reason its being ran, should be investigated but you haven’t provided enough information to do that

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here! A lot of VM infected (DC and Hypervisor too). Windows Defender detect and stop the process, but not detect the attacker. Kaspersky Anti-ransomware tool detect two types of infection: trojan.win32.bazon.a and trojan.win32.genautorunserviceimagepath.a

All versions of windows server are affected by the problem.
Task manager CPU usage show 100% in many powershell tasks. It's easy possible to kill the process.

We found a "cmd.bat" in windows autostart menu' and a powershell script in C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\

Hope to help you!